# Running selenium issue

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to selenium just started learning it using freecodecamp and started using selenium
downloaded selenium using the following command in python

```
pip install selenium
```

And I manually installed chrome web driver.
Written the code as:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

os.environ["PATH"] +=r"C:/seleniumDrivers" #where the chrome driver is installed
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

The following error occured when I run this:

```
line 81, in start
raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be 
in 
PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

But if I modified code a bit:

```
  import os
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/seleniumDrivers/chromedriver.exe)
```

A pop website appeared and closes immediately.
Can anyone please suggest what should I do.

Answer (score 2):

In the newer selenium, including the webdriver is depreciated. Use ChromeDriverManager instead of referencing the path to chromedriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: Might want to include the command for chromedriver the pip.

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home

You have to point the PATH to the correct directory, which containing the `chromedriver.exe` executable on the first level (i.e. you can see the executable when you open the path, it usually named `bin`)

For the second issue

> A pop website appeared and closes immediately. Can anyone please suggest what should I do.

It is because the code has finished (no further code to execute), so the program exits and closes the browser. You can try adding `input()` after the last line to see if the browser remains open (until you press enter on the command line).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the os module unless this is specific to your script, you can save the path as a variable. I'm using Selenium currently and this should work for you - you need to specify the "Service" now in the webdriver. Do the 2 pip installs first in terminal.

```python
# pip install selenium #
# pip install webdriver-manager #

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver

service = Service("C:/seleniumDrivers/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get(URL)
```